# How to write scalatest unit test for scala object?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest

I am trying to write a unit test for **scala object** with using **scalatest** but.
I imported the following dependencies for my `sbt`;

`libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test"`

How to write the test case for this code?

```
object Word {

  def readFile(): Map[String, Int] = {
    val counter = scala.io.Source.fromFile("filepath")
      .getLines.flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
      .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]) {
        (count, word) =>
          count + (word ->
            (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1))
      }
    counter
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to ask ? Please add details to your question what problem you are facing?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. here I want to ask, using above dependencies i need to implement a test case for scala object which as follows:

Comment: That's fine but what issue you are facing? Actually provide more information for your question only then anyone could help you.

Comment: `def readFile(): Map[String, Int] ={
    val counter = scala.io.Source.fromFile("Data\\Reading.txt")
      .getLines
      .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
      .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]){
        (count, word) => count + (word -> (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1))
      }
    return counter
  }`

Comment: so i need to implement sacalatest for the above method in the `object Word`

Comment: `object Word {

  def readFile(): Map[String, Int] ={
    val counter = scala.io.Source.fromFile("Data\\Reading.txt")
      .getLines
      .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
      .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]){
        (count, word) => count + (word -> (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1))
      }
    return counter
  }
}`
 here this is full code which i need to implement  a scalatest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to write test for it. There are libraries like FlatSpec, FunSuit.
So here, i am going to write test case for it using FunSuit

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class WordTest extends FunSuite {

  test("should return word count ") {
    val wordCount = Word.readFile()

    assert(wordCount.nonEmpty)
  }
}
```